# How can I create an XFDF file from a PDF?

Tags: pdf, forms, adobe-acrobat

How can I create an XFDF file from a PDF either
1) using Acrobat 8 Pro; or
2) using open source tools

I tried creating the XFDF by hand, but I'm not able to merge it back into the PDF. I presume it's because it is a multipage PDF form. That's why I'd like to generate a working XFDF file as a template.

Comment: hi, SO is for programming related questions, but we have a lot of StackExchange sites created for other topics (for this your question you probably will find more help at http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Alternatively you can use Foxit Reader to create an .xfa (choose .xml) or an .XDP file. Both are almost similar .xml files. 
Foxit Reader -> Form -> Export -> To File

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load your form in Acrobat 8, fill it and the select in the main menu Forms > Manage form data > Export data and choose XFDF format. The XFDF file content is not related to the number of pages in the PDF form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to do that even before, but the only 2 options I have there are .xml and .xdp. I don't know why that dialog doesn't offer me .xfdf or .fdf. Any idea?

Comment: @user323094 - it seems that you have an Adobe LiveCycle Designer form, not a plain old Acrobat form. LiveCycle Designer forms can import/export data only in XML and XDP formats, XFDF is not supported.

Comment: @Sorin Nistor: thanks, that must be it. How can I convert the form to the "plain old" format? If that's not possible, how do I create a new form in the correct format?

Comment: I recreated the form in Acrobat 8 Pro without using LiveCycle Designer and the fdf and xfdf formats are now offered. Thanks again.